# Dynamic controller include in Ember

Tags: ember.js

```
App.ListingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  queryParams: ['referrer'],
  referrer: null,

  listings: function(){
    return this.controllerFor(this.get('referrer')).get('model.content');
  }.property('referrer')
});
```

The above code works, but gives a deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION: Controller#controllerFor is deprecated, please use Controller#needs instead
```

However, because the referenced controller's name is based on the param string passed in, this needs to be done dynamically. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Is there a way you could do this in the route?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be a problem to just include all the potential controllers in your `needs` array?  If there are only a handful, you can just add them all to `needs` and get access to whichever one you need at runtime.  I'm not sure you can dynamically add items to `needs`, as I believe the complete array must be present when the controller initializes.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add to `needs`:

```
this.get('needs').pushObject(this.get('referrer'));
```

Then you can use the new controller’s model:

```
this.get('controllers.' + this.get('referrer') + '.model');
```

You might have to be smart about not adding duplicates to `needs`.

Comment: The referrer is 'inbox.summary'. I set the 'needs' following your suggestion, then try to get the model. I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: <App.ListingController:ember484>#needs does not include `inbox`. To access the inbox controller from <App.ListingController:ember484>, <App.ListingController:ember484> should have a `needs` property that is an array of the controllers it has access to.

Comment: Where did you set `needs`?

Comment: What is the controller name? `SummaryController`? `InboxSummary`? The `.` in `inbox.summary` looks out of place...